# Reference HTML elements in JS objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I dynamically create an element using JQuerys:

```
$("<div>",{id : "list"}).html("hello").appendTo("body");
```

and create a JS object using:

```
var obj = {el : document.querySelector("#list") }
```

the console returns the following when printing `obj.el` as expected:

```
<div id="list">hello</div>
```

Now I can set the content using `obj.el.innerHTML = "foo";`
After deleting the element using:

```
$("#list").remove();
```

The element **remains** in the object obj previously created. Printing `obj.el` still returns: `<div id="list">hello</div>`

First of all, why is that the case?
Is there a way to store a preference to an element without storing a complicated nested CSS selector which would slow things down?

Comment: You are deleting from the DOM, not the object. You would still need to unset (delete) the object from `window` object using `delete obj`

Comment: The console maybe using cache to show the deleted element. To make sure it is deleted try accessing the element again. This should cause a definite error.

Comment: @jeff Reusing the element does not cause an error. Chromes console lets me change the elements contents without any problems. The element can then be outputted with it's new content using the console...
I was hoping for something like typeof(obj.el) == "undefined" after deleting the element from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Read this little example i think can help you.

```js
// it would be in you code : $("<div>",{id : "list"}).html("hello").appendTo("body");
var obj = {
  a : 5
};

// let me create this object to better undersatnding
var obj2 = {
  a : 3
};

document.write(obj.a + "<br>"); // 5
document.write(obj2.a + "<br>"); // 3


// it would be in you code :var obj = {el : document.querySelector("#list") }
obj2.a = obj.a; //


document.write(obj2.a + "<br>"); // 5

//it would be in you code : $("#list").remove();
delete obj.a;

// here we still have something for obj2
document.write(obj2.a + "<br>"); // 5

// try again :
obj2.a = obj.a;
document.write(obj2.a + "<br>"); // undefined
```

In you case if you try :

```
$("#list").remove();
var obj = {el : document.querySelector("#list") }
```

I think that obj will be undefined !

Comment: Thanks for the example! The part I don't get is why JS would store an entire HTML element in a object if it already exists in the DOM. Why not create a reference? Is there a way to achieve just that?

Comment: it is exactly what it does ! it is a reference to the object not the Dom object !

Comment: @tlaloc a very good page about all this things : [Memory Management](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) , particulary in your case 'Garbage collection'

Comment: So how come I don't get an error when I try accessing a deleted DOM element via it's (no longer valid) reference? Shouldn't I get some kind of error?
Thanks for the link @Anonymous0day!

Comment: @tlaloc the garbage collector don't delete it until it have a reference to it ! if you have 2 obj. referencing same object, when the first remove occur, it act on the reference not the object, the garbage collector keep in mind that the first obj have no reference to object but second obj reference it. when we delete second obj garbage collector haven't yet any reference to the object and it destroy the object

Answer (score 0):

You can use getter and setter for el property. Instead of storing element in el, populate value of el when it gets accessed.

The obj will become

```
var obj = {
  get el(){
    return document.querySelector("#list");
  }
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/14a3x87j/1/) is demo which might help you.